# Why does my ArcGIS License Manager have a Repair option?

Tags: arcgis-license-manager

This minor problem with my ArcGIS 10.4 license manager was bugging me - why was there a Repair option, and why didn't Repair actually work?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer came from Esri tech support, and I'm including it here in case it helps someone else:

> **Clearing trusted storage for ArcGIS Licenses:**
>
> 1: Show Hidden Folders
>
> 2: Backup the files from C:/ProgramData/FLEXnet and delete this folder
>
> 3: Verify that the licenses are removed (Open the ArcGIS Administrator, click the Availability folder, it should be cleared out)
>
> 4: Reauthorise licenses

Comment: I had to stop the ArcGIS license server service that was running on the machine before I could delete the files from the FLEXnet folder.